# Ho to teleport an an armor stand to a player who just got a kill, then take it away

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to make kill signs, so when you kill someone, it teleports an armor stand in front of you, doing a cool killing pose, then teleports back to some location. How should I do this?

I did try /scoreboard objectives add kill Kills, then /tp ArmorStand @a[kill = 1] , I literrally have NO IDEA

Comment: How much help do you want? Do you want help with the teleportation, the armour stand posing, or both?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: I did! I tried /scoreboard objectives add kill Kills, then /tp ArmorStand @a[kill = 1] , I literrally have NO IDEA

Comment: To answer Ben, I just need help with the teleportation.

Comment: It's a good idea to add that to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
/tp ArmorStand @a[score_Kills_min=1]

Comment: Do you know how I would subract 1 kill score from that player?